# How to get Distinct records in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server table looks like following

```
 Id     Date                Msg
 1    01-01-2015             A
 1    02-01-2015             B
 2    03-01-2015             C
```

I want to write a query to get result as following

```
   Id          Date            Msg
    1           02-01-2015      B
    2           03-01-2015      C
```

I am trying

```
 SELECT Id,Max(Date) , Msg
 Group By Id, Msg
```

This returns me first row as well. I want Msg for Max date for a Particular Id.

Any suggestion Please

Comment: You can't SELECT it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Window Function`

```
SELECT Id,
       Date,
       Msg
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER (partition BY Id ORDER BY [Date] DESC ) rn
        FROM   tablename) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Another way is find the max `date` per `Id` in `subquery` then `join` the result with the main table. Try this.

```
SELECT Id,
       Date,
       Msg
FROM   tablename a
       JOIN (SELECT Id,
                    Max([Date])[Date]
             FROM   tablename
             GROUP  BY Id) B
         ON a.Id = b.id
            AND a.[Date] = b.[Date]
```

Comment: This returns significantly less number of rows. I want same number of rows as we may get with Msg column. What i need is Id and Max Date and Msg against that Max date. Means the number of rows should be same even if i remove Msg from Select and Group By list

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications - Both the queries working as expected. Check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e0a/1 and http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e0a/5

Answer (score 0):

The simple way get max date row in where clause

Here is the simple example query ;

```
SELECT * FROM   TABLE  T1  
WHERE  T1.TIME = (SELECT MAX(TIME) FROM TABLE  WHERE ID = T1.ID )
```